# MonetaryConversions functions of java-money module do not work

Tags: java, javafx, java-money

JavaFX Application raises an error when I try to call any MonetaryConversions function. The error message cointains

> org.javamoney.moneta.spi.loader.ResourceCache: module
> org.javamoney.moneta does not declare `uses`
> org.javamoney.moneta.spi.loader.LoaderService: Provider org.javamoney.moneta.spi.loader.DefaultLoaderService could not be instantiated

Ther error occurs when I call (javax.money.convert.MonetaryConversions was imported):

```
System.out.println(MonetaryConversions.getDefaultConversionProviderChain());
```

Module-info.java contains:

```
requires java.money;
requires org.javamoney.moneta;
```

Also when I call another java-money function from another class it works. For example:

```
System.out.println(Monetary.getCurrency("USD"));
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need an [`opens`](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) clause.